# Хранение изменений в ячейки таблицы Access

Tags: visual-basic, ms-access

Есть форма, в которой оператор вносит некие значения, из выборки он выбирает один из городов представленных в списке. Его выбор фиксируется в таблице "основная". При этом хотелось бы, что бы эти данные так же отправлялись в таблицу "Архив" и копились там. В принципе я уже написал код который их там сохраняет. Проблема в том, что я ни как не могу понять как реализовывать таблицу которая хранит хронологию изменений ячейки, и как к ней потом обращаться, ведь получается, что записи в поле "индекс" в таблице "основная" должны быть связаны с названием полей из таблицы "Архив"... Подскажите пожалуйста, вообще можно ли реализовать хранение измерений в Access таблицах, если можно то как?

[Пример базы](https://yadi.sk/d/XwyYmgFV3am7Bv)

Comment: Вы хотите, что-бы у вас все сохранялось в архив? А что значат поля 100,200,300?

Comment: Ну типо того, хотел что бы велись архивные данные.
Вообщем то разобрался уже:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем организовал таким образом. Создаем таблицу с вариантами выходных значений. Это будет "Основная". А в архивной таблице по сути будут те же поля, только имеющие тип с подстановкой. А так же графа дата, которая будет символизировать время записи... Вот и все.

Как то так получилось:

[Ответ на вопрос](https://yadi.sk/d/3q3MEj3k3apVim)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/288132)

Comment: Добавил, спасибо за замечание:)